# Where does UBB store its settings?

Tags: forum, database

We're moving a UBB forum from one host to another. (This is temporary; we're going to replace the forum eventually, but moving hosts has a higher priority.) We don't have a lot of experience with UBB, so we're feeling our way along in the dark.

We got the UBB code installed on the new host, and we've done a dry-run database export from the original site to the new site. However, almost everything set in UBB's Control Panel section didn't come with the database export.

If UBB doesn't store this data in the database, where is it stored? And if it is in the database, why would it not show up in a new forum when the database is imported? Did we somehow miss a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha. The settings are saved in the "includes" directory within the UBB code directory. Most of the fields are stored in a `config.inc.php` file.